# How I can optimise the below query to make it faster

Tags: performance, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an sql query which is not taking too much time for execution in production because of too much data please suggest me how I can optimise the below query.

```
SELECT cite_value 
FROM xyz  
WHERE UPPER ( cite_value ) LIKE UPPER ( 'fl%' ) 
AND version = 0 AND segment_uuid=element_uuid 
AND ROWNUM <= 20 ORDER BY cite_value
```

Below is the execution plan screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I could really use a description of the other tables you're working with here.  It would be beneficial to provide descriptions of the tables you are interacting with here.

Comment: please find the execution plan of the table at the following location:    http://i.stack.imgur.com/7O0qd.png also for information I should tell you that UPPER ( cite_value ) is the indexed column

Comment: This will likely be guesswork if we don't know your indexes, your hardware, your DB size, etc. Can you provide us with a more detailed plan, ideally in text form?